# pose estimation

Tags: matlab, 3d, camera-calibration, perspectivecamera

With your help, I have been able yo use CvPosit to estimate the camera pose (using this link http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/posit/ ). I am using MATLAB code.

Now I am looking to verify that pose by projecting 3D points on the image coordinates. The details are as follows:

1. Let's say Image Points and World Points for the Cube are:

   ```
   World Points=[28 28 -28;-28 28 -28;28 -28 -28, 28 28 28]
   Image_Points=[-4 29;-180 86;-5 -102;76 137];
   ```
2. The obtained Pose is:

   ```
   Pose =[0.896 0.0101 0.4439 -13.9708;-0.3031 0.7127 0.6326 13.7039;-0.3100 -0.701 0.6416 164.5663;0 0 0 1];
   ```

   I have used 640 as focal length in my example. Now from this pose, I want to use a 3D point and project it back to get 2D image point. Ideally I should get the same point. But I cannot get it. I am using the following way in MATLAB:
3. Let's say `P = [28;28;28;28;1]    % 4 X 1 matrix for a 3D point`

   ```
   P_Camera= Pose *  P;  

   Calibration Matrix (K)=[640 0 0 0;0 640 0 0;0 0 1 0;0 0 0 1];

   Image Points= P_Camera*K;
   ```

   I get `x = 15251` and `y = 27447`. I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Please, help me out!!

Answer (score 1):

camera pose or camera extrinsic parameters are composed of rotation R and translation t. I believe that your Pose matrix is actually `[R t; [0 0 0 1]]`. To transform 3D homogeneous points(4x1) in to camera coordinates you need to:

```
Xcam = K*[R t]*Xworld
```

where K is the 3x3 [camera matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix), containing the camera intrinsic (internal) parameters.
by playing with your numbers a bit, if you will set K as:

```
K =

3.3202         0   -0.0229
     0    3.3202    0.0153
     0         0    1.0000
```

you will get a close answer ( this K doesn't fit with your data of F=640, but it is the LS solution with the input points and pose).
there are still some error though. Try calibrating your camera and taking optical distortion into account (there is a good camera calibration toolbox for Matlab  [here](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/).